# AJAX - XMLHttpRequest open php file outside htdocs

Tags: php, ajax

Here is the simplified code, I am calling JS inside epr_lib.php.

epr_lib.php is located in cgi-bin folder, that means outside htdocs.

In cgi-bin folder I have these files: epr_lib.php; newrequest.php.

My question is: how can I call in ajaxRequest.open the file that is outside htdocs? Or this is impossible?

```
var ajaxRequest;
ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        suppl_addrss.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "newrequest.php?task=getsuppladdrss", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Ajax requests make http requests for the file, so you'd have to have it available in htdocs.

You could create a proxy script that loads the cgi-bin file.  Just create a file that will include your cgi-bin file:

```
// myproxy.php
// you'll have to get the querystring and use it as a variable in newrequest.php
$vars = $_GET("task");
include('../cgi-bin/newrequest.php');
```